# Calculation of product of gamma functions.

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

I want to study the asymptotic behaviour of the product

$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3i)!.
$$

A first attempt has been to transform the internal factorial to the gamma function, bearing in mind that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, and therefore $(3i)!=\Gamma(3i+1)$, for all $i\in\{0,1,\dots, n-1\}$.

However, this brings me to the problem of computing
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \Gamma(3i+1),
$$
to which one cannot apply Gauss's Multiplication Formula, which is one of the few ways I have seen to calculate the product of Gammas.

PS: I have already considered approximating the factorial by Stirling's formula, but this is incorrect since this approximation is for "large" values of the factorial, and in this case the value $(3i)!$ may not take "large" values and therefore the asymptotic approximation is not correct.

Comment: Use https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Product+Gamma%283i%2B1%29+from+i%3D0+to+n-1 and the standard asymptotics of the Barnes $G$-function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function#Asymptotic_expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the Barnes G-function (as mentioned by @Gary in comments), use
$$\log (\Gamma (3 i+1))=3 i (\log (i)-1+\log (3))+\frac{1}{2} (\log (i)+\log (2 \pi )+\log
   (3))+$$ $$\frac{1}{36 i}-\frac{1}{9720
   i^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^5}\right)$$ Summing from $i=1$ to $i=n-1$,  gives for the logarithm of the product
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(6 \log (H(n-1))+\log \left(\frac{(1)_{n-1}}{6 \pi
   }\right)+n \left(n (\log (27)-3)+3+\log \left(\frac{2 \pi
   }{9}\right)\right)\right)+\frac{H_{n-1}}{36}-\frac{H_{n-1}^{(3)}}{   9720}$$ where $H(n-1)$ is the hyperfactorial function; the other terms are Pochhammer symbols and generalized harmonic numbers.

This works quite well even for small values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 1.7917564 & 1.7917595 \\
 3 & 8.3710076 & 8.3710107 \\
 4 & 21.172835 & 21.172838 \\
 5 & 41.160050 & 41.160053 \\
 6 & 69.059321 & 69.059324 \\
 7 & 105.45477 & 105.45477 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, using series expansion for large $n$
$$\color{blue}{\log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \Gamma(3i+1)\right)=\frac{3}{4} n^2 \log \left(\frac{9 n^2}{e^3}\right)+n \log \left(\frac{e \sqrt{2 \pi }}{3 n}\right)+}$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac 1{36} \log(n)+\Big[3 \log (A)-\frac{\zeta (3)}{9720}+\frac{\gamma }{36}-\frac{1}{4}
   \log (18 \pi ) \Big]+}$$ $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{36 n}+\frac{37}{19440 n^2}-\frac{13}{9720
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)}$$
Repeating the same calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 1.7917647 & 1.7917595 \\
 3 & 8.3710100 & 8.3710107 \\
 4 & 21.172836 & 21.172838 \\
 5 & 41.160050 & 41.160053 \\
 6 & 69.059321 & 69.059324 \\
 7 & 105.45477 & 105.45477 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using Barnes G-function, given by Mathematica, the asymptotic of the product would be
$$\frac{ 2^{\frac{5 n-3}{2}}}{A^3}\times 3^{\frac{(n-1) (3 n-4)}{2} }\times \exp\left(-\frac{9 }{4}n^2+n+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{36 n} \right)\times n^{\frac{3}{2}n^2-n+\frac{1}{36}}\times$$ $$\pi ^{\frac{3 n-1}{2}} \left(G\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) G\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\right)^{n-2}\times \left(G\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)
   G\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)\right)^{1-n}$$where $A$ is Glaisher's constant.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that it does not capture the constant term correctly. You can however see that the two harmonic number terms can be replaced by $C+o(1)$ with some constant $C$. The explicit form of $C$ would follow from the approach I suggested. You may also just compute it numerically to high accuracy.

Comment: @Gary. Thank you for one more constructive comment. Cheers :-)

Comment: It works incredibly well! Could you tell me the reference where you got the first approximation from?

Comment: @MarcMunar You should consider the second approximation. The first one is not asymptotic, since the asymptotic constant is replaced by a numerical approximation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Still, do you know the way to get the approximation given by Mathematica, or the reference where you get it? I would like to have the details and not just use the Mathematica output. In addition, the comment has been modified and a new expression appears in blue. How has it been calculated?

Comment: @MarcMunar. As I wrote, I expanded the summation as series and grouped terms to make it nicer.